# ¿Cómo hacer una relación de modelos Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Probablemente se una pregunta simple pero estoy un poco confundido

Tengo los siguientes modelos:

```
class RemesaFactura(models.Model):
    remesa = models.ForeignKey(Remesa, related_name='remesa_%(class)s_objects')
    factura = models.ForeignKey(Factura,related_name='factura_(class)s_objects')


class Factura(models.Model):
     valor_factura = models.DecimalField('valor factura',max_digits=12,decimal_places=2,default=0, null=True, blank=True)


class Clasificacion(models.Model):
    factura = models.ForeignKey(Factura, null=False, blank=False, related_name='factura_%(class)s_objects')
```

Lo que trato de hacer es que a partir de "RemesaFactura" buscar las facturas dentro del modelo, luego ir
al modelo Clasificación y contar cuantas veces aparece allí

¿Cómo puedo relacionarlos para obtener datos  tanto de RemesaFactura y Clasificacion?

He intentado lo siguiente, pero resulta que me falta agregar el "id" del modelo RemesaFactura:

```
remesa_facturas = RemesaFactura.objects.filter(
                Q(remesa_id=remesa_id) & (Q(remesa__numero__istartswith=search))
            ).distinct().values_list('factura_id', flat=1)

            data = Clasificacion.objects.filter(
                Q(factura__id__in=remesa_facturas)
            ).order_by().values('factura__id', 'factura__valor_factura', 'factura__numero')\
             .annotate(cantidad=Count('factura__id')).distinct()

     #resultado 
<QuerySet [{'factura__numero': '255550', 'factura__valor_factura': Decimal('5600.00'), 'factura__id': 7, 'cantidad': 1}]>
```